# How can I run multiple python scripts at once from different folders?

Tags: python-3.x

I have **FOLDER1** **FOLDER2** **FOLDER3**. All of those contain a **PYTHON_CODE.py**, all of the folders are located in the same place. How can I run all three **PYTHON_CODE.py** from all of the three folder?

Is it possible to make them all run at the same time, and **NOT** in the way that first **FOLDER1**'s **PYTHON_CODE.py** finishes, then comes the second one and third (Again, NOT this way).

Comment: You can try the multiprocessing library.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a higher level script located in the main folder that calls your others scripts to run them in parallel.

You can use the `os` module (in particular the `os.system` function) to define a function which runs the script passed as argument.

Then, exploiting the `multiprocessing` module, you can spawn processes to be run in parallel by means of the `Pool` object.

The `Pool.map` function distributes the works among the defined processes, in a parallel manner.

[Here](https://datasciencebeginners.com/2018/10/24/running-python-processes-in-parallel-getting-started/) you can find a good example for you case.

References:

- [`multiprocessing` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)
- [`os` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os#module-os)